# pandas - how to search for whole word in the row

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I need to search and drop rows that has a complete sentence contains in in the cell.
I tried with `df = df[~df.datacell.str.contains("find my string in this column")]` But seems like it drops all the rows that has any one or more words in the sentence.

Comment: Use `df[~df.datacell.eq("find my string in this column")]` or `df[~(df.datacell == "find my string in this column")]`

Comment: @jezrael will it drop only if its a complete match? my cell may contain additional words before and after of this sentence: `you need to find my string in the column`

Comment: Can you add some sample to question with expected output?